# How to add jquery .not() in this?

Tags: jquery, html

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
       $('body').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(4px)');
    });
```

When button is pressed, everything turns blur, i want to add the .not() to that so the "login" div doesn't get blurred as well when the button is pressed. how do i add that in? i am new to jquery, cheers!

Comment: can you not just add something like this `$('.loginDiv').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(0px)');`?

Comment: yeah i don't know where to add it in

Comment: please clearify on `the "login" div `. Is this a div with a class login?

Comment: well that doesn't work @wf4

Comment: @user3008011 the div name is login, so it should be #login

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is impossible, because of the same problem as opacity. Everything inside the body will be blurred.

If you want this to work you need to blur a container or wrapping div.

```
<body>
    <div id="loginDiv">
        Your login window goes here
    </div>
    <div id="containerDiv">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

If you blurred the containerDiv and positioned the loginDiv above it with z-index, it would give you the desired results.

Comment: ah... but i've been styling the body in css :/

Comment: Give your containerDiv a height and width of 100% and set the same background picture to it.

Comment: i didn't use background pictures, just css attributes. i replaced body with #container after making the div in css, and everything is out of place haha, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Remember to check if you have position on the body. If so, put the same on the #container.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding some css? http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Ng/2/

```
.blurred * {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}

#login, .blurred #login * {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('blurred');
})
```